# It's there a way to close a toast with an external event?

Tags: javascript, toastr

I have a react component that wraps some content that it's not available in screens under 1024px if the user resizes the screen an event will be triggered opening a toast that only can be closed clicking it, but if the user resizes up the resolution again I want to close this toast automatically.
It's there a way to force a specific toast to close assigning some kind of id to find it and clicking it with javascript?

```js
// this calls a generic function that opens a toast.
manageWarning('', 'You are running on a small screen resolution, this feature it\'s only available on screens up to 1024 px, please scale up the window again', true);

// This is the generic function
export function manageWarning(id, message, disableAutoClose) {
    toastr.options.timeOut = disableAutoClose ? 0 : Global.MESSAGE_ERROR_DURATION;
    toastr.options.extendedTimeOut = disableAutoClose ? 0 : toastr.options.extendedTimeOut;
    toastr.warning(message);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to fix it with some changes to my code base.

The manage warning method now returns the toast itself

```js
export function manageWarning(id, message, disableAutoClose) {
    toastr.options.timeOut = disableAutoClose ? 0 : Global.MESSAGE_ERROR_DURATION;
    toastr.options.extendedTimeOut = disableAutoClose ? 0 : 
    toastr.options.extendedTimeOut;
    return toastr.warning(message);
}
```

Now the consumer can save the reference of this toast

```js
this.toast = manageWarning('', 'You are running on a small screen resolution, this feature it\'s only available on screens up to 1024 px, please scale up the window again', true);
```

With this in mind now I can just simply call

```js
this.toast.fadeIn(); // Method to show the toast again.
this.toast.fadeOut(); // Method close the toast.
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no way of tagging specific toasts with an ID using the default behaviour of the plugin.

If you are only going to display one toast and you want to clear it (or all displayed toasts) then just use

```
toastr.clear();
```

If you have a scenario where you may display more than one toast and you want to remove a specific toast, then you can get the toast container using

```
$('#toast-container');
```

Or get an array of all toasts with

```
$('#toast-container').children();
```

Once you have that you can find your specific toast and use .remove();

```
$('#toast-container').children()[1].remove();
```

Hope this helps

Comment: This totally works but doesn't fit exactly with my needs, I managed to fix the problem, watch the answer if you are curious, and thanks for your answer.