# Closing the toastr notification after a certain process?

Tags: c#, webforms, toastr

I am using toastR in my ASP.Net WebForms application. I have this code to show a notification to the user for the whole application.

```
private void ShowToastr(Page.Page page, string message, string title, string type = "info", bool tapToDismiss = false)
{
    page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(page.GetType(), "toastr_message",
    String.Format("toastr.{0}('{1}', '{2}', '{3}');", type.ToLower(), message, title, tapToDismiss), addScriptTags: true);
}
```

But, the problem is, the `tapToDismiss` is not working.

How can I stop the closing of toastr notification when the process is running and close it after the process?

Comment: Do the answers in this question help? https://stackoverflow.com/q/55826389/6060429